# Jenkins fails to send email - Authentication Required

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins server running on a Linux VM. I would like my Jenkins to send me an email every time a build gets started. I have set the email service up as below. As I am using 2 factor authentication for my google account, I have created an app password for Jenkins, but it still says "authentication required". I have also installed the Extended E-mail notification plugin and set it up the exact same way with the same result. Does anyone know what could be the issue here?

[image: Email]

Comment: Which version of the Mailer Plugin?

Comment: I'm using the newest, version 2.66

Comment: I think you've checked `Email Extension Plugin`. I am asking about `Mailer` plugin version.

Comment: Oh, that's 1.24.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did a test set up and tried using exactly your configuration. I too faced the same issue. Since i had tested this thing long time ago and it worked well then, i knew it had to do with some change in latest plugin version. So i tried downgrading the [Mailer](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Mailer) plugin from version `1.24` to `1.23` and it worked. :)

You can get the Mailer plugin version `1.23` [here](https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/mailer/1.23/mailer.hpi).

Details about downgrading a given plugin's version is described [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/#advanced-installation)

Note: You don't have to configure `Extended E-mail Notification` section for this to work. Just leave it as is.