# Jenkins " Test e-mail recipient" throwing error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have installed jenkins(version 2.176.3) recently and when i try to test my "E-mail Notification" configuration i am getting below error,

I have tried to reinstall multiple versions of jenkins but still getting same result.

Looks like username and password field(under "use smtp authentication") is not getting saved which is causing this issue :(

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.util.Secret$1.convert(Secret.java:306)
    at hudson.util.Secret$1.convert(Secret.java:304)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.AnnotationHandler.convert(AnnotationHandler.java:66)
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide the configuration (after hiding any sensitive info) that you have used in the E-mail section.

Comment: Hi..i just observed that username and password field of email(below "use smtp authentication") authentication is not getting saved and in post data of test  email  also these two parameter does not exist...looks like this is causing this issue..any idea why these fields are not getting saved?

Comment: What version of [Mailer](https://plugins.jenkins.io/mailer) plugin do you have installed? Please see this and let me know if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57620981/jenkins-fails-to-send-email-authentication-required/57621730#57621730

Comment: @Technext Downgrading Mailer plugin resolved this issue..Thank you sooo much for your help.

Mailer version was 1.25 and i have downgraded to 1.23 and this resolved my issue.I hope downgrading this plugin will not impact any other dependable pugins.

Comment: I've run into the same issue with Mailer 1.25. Downgraded to 1.24 and worked. Thanks.

Comment: If it helped you guys, kindly [upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) the answer. :) @SadhaNanda: Downgrading should not affect other plugins.

Comment: @SadhaNanda: I meant upvoting this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57620981/jenkins-fails-to-send-email-authentication-required/57621730#57621730 :)

Comment: Did somebody log an issue on issues.jenkins-ci.org regarding this error?

Comment: Seems someone did post about it: [JENKINS-59161](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-59161)

Comment: Issue fixed in version 1.26 https://github.com/jenkinsci/mailer-plugin/releases/tag/mailer-1.26