# Configure Jenkins to send gmail: What am I missing?

Tags: jenkins, gmail

Trying to have Jenkins send an email to a Gmail account upon every build. I get:

Failed to send out e-mail

com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError 9sm5733284oij.25 - gsm

Here's what I tried so far:

Made the gmail account accept emails from less secure apps

Generated an application password from gmail and used it in my Jenkins configuration - got the same error with and without the app password

Looked at at least a dozen answers (yeah) and all the screens showing the Jenkins gmail config look the same as mine

telnet smpt.gmail.com 465 responds as connected

My Jenkins install is localhost using this URL:  http://192.168.0.1:8080/
My system admin email address exists and is entered in Jenkins

I've tried filling in the section on Extended E-mail notification and removing the entries - no difference

Turned off Windows Defender, thinking, just maybe???

Also tried to configure Outlook/Hotmail using those smpt parms but that gave different errors

Don't know if this matters but I have that 'It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken' and I don't recall setting up a reverse proxy!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Set up Jenkins email notification as shown below:

[image: Jenkins email configuration for Gmail]

Comment: I'm using the most current version of Jenkins downloaded this morning (9/4)

Comment: And stopped Windscribe VPN service - still errors out

Comment: And I also activated my account based on the info here:

https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Comment: If you're using version `1.24` or `1.25` of [Mailer](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Mailer) plugin, then there is [issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-59161) in it. Check this answer for further help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57620981/jenkins-fails-to-send-email-authentication-required/57621730#57621730

Comment: Mr. Technext - that did it!!! I upgraded mailer to 1.26 and I successfully sent an email!
Thanks so much.......

How do I credit you with the solution to my problem?

Comment: If you liked this answer, kindly upvote it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57620981/jenkins-fails-to-send-email-authentication-required/57621730#57621730

Comment: Now Jenkins is failing to send emails when a build is bad with auth errors.

The 'Test Email' in Jenkins System config works - gmail receives the test email but when a build fails I'm getting auth errors.

Yesterday Jenkins WAS sending emails on build failures; today it is not.

Comment: Are you using `1.23` now or have you upgraded? [JENKINS-59161](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-59161) was closed 2-3 days ago with some latest release but it seems the issue has not got fixed as stated in the link above. So, in case you are not on `1.23` any more, then you should revert to that version. If you're facing issue on `1.23`, then you should comment on that open ticket so they know about it.

Comment: Hey Technext!
Downgraded mailer to 1.23 now everything is working again.
You're a lifesaver - just saying.....

Comment: I'm glad i could help again! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this, [create & use app passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en-gb) with [2-step verification](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839) turned on.

A less secure method is to [allow less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en-gb) without 2-step verification.

Comment: Thanks... I tried this didn't have any luck.
I'll do it again just to be sure I didn't miss anything

Comment: this approach no longer works since google disabled it