# Configure email notification jenkins

Tags: email, jenkins, notifications

I want to configure email notification for my jobs,however getting no email notification in post failure.

Note:email configuration test was successful.

Getting below error:

Sending e-mails to: *********@gmail.com
ERROR: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError g201sm5218708wmg.34 - gsmtp

com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError g201sm5218708wmg.34 - gsmtp

```
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2057)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1580)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1097)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at hudson.tasks.MailSender.run(MailSender.java:130)
at hudson.tasks.MailSender.execute(MailSender.java:105)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.cleanUp(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1095)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1862)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

Finished: UNSTABLE

Comment: Are your jenkins able to send mails?

Comment: If you're using version `1.24` or `1.25` of [Mailer](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Mailer) plugin, then there is [issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-59161) in it. Check this answer for further help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57620981/jenkins-fails-to-send-email-authentication-required/57621730#57621730

Comment: I noticed something very strange!  The jenkins email configuration stores some default password and do not let me store the actual password of the email I am setting up and I end up getting authentication error post the build: 530 5.5.1 Authentication Required.