# Jenkins email notification issue-Unresolved

Tags: email, jenkins

Sending emails to: ********@gmail.com

> `ERROR: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError x5sm3361367wrg.69 - gsmtp`
>
> `com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError x5sm3361367wrg.69 - gsmtp`

- Jenkins version:Jenkins ver. 2.193
- Mailer plugin:1.27
- Email Extension Plugin-2.66

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure email notification jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57928561/configure-email-notification-jenkins)

Answer (score 0):

In 'Configuration - Extended E-mail Notification', have you tried ticking 'Allow sending to unregistered users'?

Comment: Yes,tried this as well.Still getting error as:ERROR: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError u11sm3219601wmd.32 - gsmtp