# Jenkins Email Configuration- error "AuthenticationFailedException"

Tags: java, jenkins

I've installed my jenkins on AWS ec2 Instance and using private subnet and both the port configured in security group of the instance. I'm getting the same error for both cases-
port - 465 ssl checked or port 587 ssl unchecked
and I'm typing in my password correctly but I still run into this AuthenticaionFailedException.

The settings I used are:

```
SMTP SERVER: smtp.gmail.com 
Default user e-mail suffix: @gmail.com
USERNAME: username@gmail.com 
PASSWORD: password
USE SSL: checked/unchecked
PORT: 465/587
Reply-to-address: 
Charset: UTF-8
```

Error I'm getting-

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and 
Password not accepted. Learn more a 535 5.7.8  
https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 
q13sm22788500pfn.150 - gsmtp

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:809)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:752)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:669)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at hudson.tasks.Mailer$DescriptorImpl.doSendTestMail(Mailer.java:672)
at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:396)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:408)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.interceptor.RequirePOST$Processor.invoke(RequirePOST.java:77)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.invoke(PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.java:26)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:212)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:145)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:535)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:747)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:878)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:280)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:747)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:878)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:676)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
at jenkins.telemetry.impl.UserLanguages$AcceptLanguageFilter.doFilter(UserLanguages.java:128)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1701)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1668)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Note: I'm new to jenkins, aws so please try to put each and every steps so that I can able to understand and resolve this issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347269/javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception-535-5-7-8-username-and-password-not-ac) link?

Comment: Yes, I've gone through with this link but I didn't find solution.

Comment: Please check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57621730/361089) and see if it works

Comment: Thanks for your response, but still I'm facing same issue.

Comment: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbuO
534-5.7.14 RhzY9WARWhNT3JP2McVXX-C1HKWDIbUCo6GuXjLF-6Ucmh_TG6eMZ_F5vYw9X29SWUEJaN
534-5.7.14 eepjH-3kgfD9TLuXRC-P4aHUHSqyhwS-3jUgfgoxZukY8R0kMHTrDA-vTYsLum> Please
534-5.7.14 log in via your web browser and then try again.
534-5.7.14  Learn more at
534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 v5sm1327002pfv.76 - gsmtp .    I'm following all the instructions but still not able to resolve the issue.

Comment: Did you follow the steps described [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=637056792678923088-2147656284&rd=2#cantsignin) to generate `app` (in your case, Jenkins) password? If you have already done that, then you need to downgrade the [Mailer](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Mailer) plugin version to `1.23`

Comment: Thank you, now its working fine... but I want to know if we use some organization mail id then I think we can't allow less secure app setting with that organization mail. It would be risky then how we will do.

Comment: The Google link that i referred to was to suggest you use `App Password` and not the less secure option. Did you try using the `App Password` thing? Also, did you change the Mailer plugin version to get this working? What version of Mailer plugin do you have right now?

Comment: I've 1.23 version of mailer plugin right now

Comment: Were you using some other version earlier? Also, did you try using the `App Password` mentioned above?

Comment: I've tried and it was working fine but not with my organization domain. For e.g if I'll use  user.name@abc.com then it will show same error because I'm not able to do two step verification. Please help if you have any solution for this. I'm using domain mail id in gmail.

Comment: If your SMTP server is `smtp.gmail.com`, then it expects a GMail credentail. You will have to check with your company and get their SMTP server details to get things working.

Comment: Can't we find smtp server details

Comment: Outlook (in case you use it) Account settings might be one place to look for. I suggest you just contact your system admin, explain what you're trying to achieve and get the details.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now, it's working fine.

Comment: What did you do?

Answer (score 3):

These settings worked fine for me

**Implement Three things with given SMTP settings**

1. Disable two factor authentication: https://myaccount.google.com/security
2. Allow less secure apps : https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
3. Allow new devices using the link: https://g.co/allowaccess

**SMTP Settings:**

- smtp.gmail.com
- Port: 465
- Use SSL
- From Email Address
- Gmail Username
- Gmail Password
- Recipient Email Address