# Getting test mail from Jenkins but no mails are received when build is complete

Tags: java, email, jenkins, testing

Hi I am trying to configure sending mail to my gmail account ,however when i am sending test mail from jenkins i am receiving it successfully from jenkins to my registered email id,But when i am running job after configuring the mail list i am getting error as follows -:

```
 MessagingException message: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials v1sm3830548pjs.36 - gsmtp"
```

I have followed these steps -:

```
Gmail SMTP server address: smtp.gmail.com
Gmail SMTP user name: Your full Gmail address (e.g. example@gmail.com)
Gmail SMTP password: Your Gmail password
Gmail SMTP port: 465
Gmail SMTP TLS/SSL required: yes
```

Also tried this -:

```
sign in to gmail account >> navigate to settings >> privacy and security settings

setup two step verification settings (because without two step verification we cannot generate application specific password)

after setting up two step verification setting in gmail account navigate back to security and privacy settings

click on application specific password >> give the name of the application in the drop down as Jenkins (google by default does not have any specific application password setting for Jenkins) >> this will generate password note down the password generated.
```

I am getting test mail successfully on my gmail account however getting error when job runs .

Can somebody please help.

Comment: What version of `Mailer` plugin are you using? See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57620981/jenkins-fails-to-send-email-authentication-required/57621730#57621730) helps.

Comment: @Technext I am using v1.32 of Mailer plugin

Comment: Try downgrading to another version and see if it works

Comment: @Technext still facing the same issue